# Get a property from each level of a tree structure

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a list of objects in which each object in the list potentially has another list of the same type below it (a pretty standard tree structure). I am looking for a way to generically pull a property from every level this tree (since i want to potentially pull several of them) into a flattened list.

Object Example:

```
public class Group {

    public List<Group> SubGroups { get; set; }
    public List<OtherStuff> OtherStuffs { get; set; }
    public OtherThing Thing { get; set; }

}
```

Like so:

```
groups.FlattenProperty(g => g.Thing)
```

But still be able to

```
groups.FlattenProperty(g => g.OtherStuffs).SelectMany(s => s);
```

I don't have much control over the data structure as it is part of a legacy system so modifying the structure is really not an option.

Is there an existing solution for this that would be reasonably reusable?

Comment: What's `OtherThing`?

Comment: OtherThing is another object as a property of the Group object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FlattenProperty<T>(this Group g, Func<Group,T> transform)
{
    yield return transform(g);
    foreach(var item in g.SubGroups.SelectMany(sub => sub.FlattenProperty(transform)))
       yield return item;
}
```

This will take your lambda and apply it to the initial `Group` object and yield the result.  Then it will recursively call itself for the `SubGroups`.  The `SelectMany` will pull out the individual items from the `IEnumerable` returned by the recursive call and each item will be yeilded.

Or if you want to pass in a `IEnumerable<Group>` then it can be changed to

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FlattenProperty<T>(
    this IEnumerable<Group> groups, 
    Func<Group,T> transform)
{
    foreach(Group g in groups)
    {
        yield return transform(g);
        foreach(var item in g.SubGroups.FlattenProperty(transform))
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i think this is really close to what i was looking for, thanks! I adapted your approach and added a bit to not limit it to my particular object type so i can re-use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Slight adaptation of juharr's answer allowing for arbitrary objects that i eventually used.

```
public static IEnumerable<TV> FlattenTreeProperty<T, TV>(this IEnumerable<T> collectionToRecurse, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector, Func<T, TV> propertySelector)
{
    var itemsToRecurse = (collectionToRecurse != null ? collectionToRecurse as IList<T> ?? collectionToRecurse.ToList() : new List<T>());

    if (!itemsToRecurse.Any())
    {
        yield break;
    }

    foreach (var item in itemsToRecurse.Select(propertySelector).Where(i => i != null))
    {
        yield return item;
    }

    foreach (var itemList in itemsToRecurse.Select(childrenSelector).Where(i => i != null))
    {
        foreach (var item in itemList.FlattenTreeProperty(childrenSelector, propertySelector))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Used Like So:

```
groups.FlattenTreeProperty(g => g.SubGroups, g => g.OtherStuffs)
```

An overload on top of it to clean it up gave me exactly what i was looking for.

Edit: Fixed for sparse trees,    SelectMany throws an exception if any of the sub-items are null